# Is there a way to make a floating div tag take on the actual height it has from content

Tags: css, html, css-float, overlap

I have a floating div tag to the left and then another div tag that auto margins to the right. If I take out the contents of the right div the left div tag "overlaps" everything below it.

How could I go by fixing this so it doesn't overlap?!

I'll include a picture to show you how it overlaps.
[image: overlapping problem]

Comment: Once you float an element, it's removed from the regular document flow and won't be considered in many of the width/height calculations. It's a drawback in CSS. The only practical method to get around it is to limit the size of the element containing the "Who's online" stuff and limit to the same width as the central "Header" section immediately over it.

Comment: Could you add the code you're using? Preferably, also create a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: If I make the div that holds the floating div a certain height, it works fine, but I need it to adjust to the content rather then setting a height.

Answer (score 0):

"if I make the div that holds the floating div a certain height, it works fine, but I need it to adjust to the content rather then setting a height"

Have you tried a min-high of 1px mite work mite not